# Compound file extension syntax coloring with Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I have some files with the extension "js.php" that I would like Sublime to automatically treat as Javascript files not PHP files. Is this possible?

I tried adding `"extensions": ["js.php"]` to my user settings and then setting View->Syntax->Open All With Current Extension As ->Javascript (while a js.php file was open) but all files with just a .php extension were opened as Javascript files too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [ApplySyntax](https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax) plugin. It was written to handle just such a scenario.